# Check function input in another function - pass all parameters

Tags: r

I have a complex function with many parameters. In order to make the code more readable I thought I can move checking validity of inputs to some other function. Like in the following example:

```
complex_function <- function(a=NA, b=NA, c=NA, d=NA, e=NA, f=NA, g=NA, h=NA) {
  check_inputs(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, f=f, g=g, h=h)
  # ... rest of the function
}

check_inputs= function(a=NA, b=NA, c=NA, d=NA, e=NA, f=NA, g=NA, h=NA) {
  if(is.na(a) & is.na(c)) {
    stop("Not valid inputs - message 1")
  } else if (is.na(h)) {
    stop("Not valid inputs - message 2")
  } 
  # long list of other controls
}
```

Is it possible to call `check_inputs` without explicitly naming all parameters? Something like `check_inputs(get_all_arguments_of_parrent_function)`? Is there better way how to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this small example will help:

```
foo <- function(x,y){
    foo_call <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
    do.call(check_args,foo_call)
}

check_args <- function(x,y){
    print(x)
    print(y)
}
```

`match.call` returns a language object containing the original function call. I remove the first element, because that's the function name. The remaining elements are the arguments and their values. Then we can just pass that to `do.call` with the other function, `check_args`.

Comment: Won't that (a) lead to evaluation in the incorrect environment, and (b) require the x and y be evaluated twice?

Comment: @hadley (b) Probably, but I wasn't terribly concerned about that, (a) can you show an example where my function will print the wrong value and/or a fix?

Comment: `foo_call <- 100; foo(foo_call, 10)`. Would be better to use ... in both functions, as anything else will be error prone.

Comment: @hadley Yes, I see. Although that seems like a fairly small risk, given the ability to name `foo_call` something unlikely to cause a collision. I can see using `...` in the second function, but not `foo`. Seems like that would make documenting and using the function less clear, particularly with a lot of arguments. Specifying default values for arguments, for instance.

Comment: Then you're better of explicitly supplying the args to `check_args()` - yes, it takes more time when you're writing the function, but it will save you a lot of time when you hit an edge case because the arguments aren't evaluated in the right environment.

Comment: Here's a more pernicious example: `z <- function() {a <- 10; b <- 10; foo(x = a, y = b)}; z()`.